# Programmatic SharePoint Online Calendar Entries Missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, calendar

I have a simple Calendar. I have added an entry to the calendar through C#:

```
ListItemCreationInformation listCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(listCreationInformation);
oListItem["Title"] = "IDC Townhall2";
oListItem["Location"] = "WAR Room 9";
oListItem["EventDate"] = new DateTime(2016, 11, 10, 10, 0, 0);
oListItem["EndDate"] = new DateTime(2016, 11, 10, 11, 0, 0);
oListItem["Description"] = "Added item description";
oListItem["EventType"] = 1;
oListItem["UID"] = System.Guid.NewGuid();
oListItem.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

The code is using my credentials.

In SharePoint (using the same credentials as the C#), the entry does not appear in the Default Calendar View but does appear in the List View. Editing the entry here and updating the Title causes the entry auto-magically appear in the Calendar view.

Can someone point me in the right direction to get the programmatic entries to appear in the Calendar View.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare the item (created by c#) and item created manually. Some parameter must be missing. You can try to view all properties by using REST API in browser.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Reviewing the properties in C# showed nothing.  I think the clue is in the minimal change required to get things showing.

I will definitely try the REST idea, and provide feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Problem and solution identified (if not understood). Get rid of the line:

```
oListItem["EventType"] = 1;
```